# How to throw exception if file is empty in c++?

Tags: c++, file, exception

in below code i am trying to print message if file is empty and then throwing exception. Consider file Text.txt is empty.

```
    ifstream inputFile;
try 
{
    inputFile.exceptions(ifstream::eofbit);
    inputFile.open("Text.txt");
    if (inputFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "file opened"<<endl;
    }
    if (inputFile.peek()== ifstream::traits_type::eof())
    {
        cout << "file opened but it is empty or invalid 
    content" << endl;
    }
}
catch (ifstream::failure &e)
{
    cout << "Some issue with input file: " << e.what()<<endl;
    _exit(1);
}
```

But it is throwing exception before going into the if block (if (inputFile.peek()== ifstream::traits_type::eof())).What I am missing?

Comment: What does the exception error say?  Please add the error to your original post.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens when the file exists and it's empty.
The problem is that you enabled exceptions upon `eof` in the line: `inputFile.exceptions(ifstream::eofbit);`

It opens the file and since it's empty, it immediately sets the `eof` flag, and you get an exception. If you comment out this line, it will work OK.

Anyway, I would write the same code it a little shorter way:

```
    ifstream inputFile("Text.txt");
    if (inputFile) 
    {
        cout << "file opened" << endl;
        inputFile.peek();
        if (inputFile.eof())
        {
            cout << "file opened but it is empty or invalid content" << endl;
        }
    }
```